# transform json to add "children" in an unflatten-esque way

Tags: python, json, node.js, transform, flatten

How do I transform following input.json into output.json?

I've found [Python flatten/unflatten](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten)
and [Json flatten](https://github.com/mucbuc/json-flatten) but neither fits my need.

**input.json**

```
{
  "root": {
    "d3": {
      "Selections": [
        "d3.select",
        "d3.selectAll"
      ],
      "Transitions": [
        "d3.transition"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**output.json**

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "children": [{
    "name": "d3",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Selection",
      "children": [{
        "name": "d3.select"
      }, {
        "name": "d3.selectAll"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Transitions",
      "children": [{
        "name": "d3.transition"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get it done with following code. The output is not exactly the order, in terms of "Selections" and "Transitions", and "name" vs "children", but I'm ok with that.

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import json
import sys

def load_data(filename):
        with open(filename) as data_file:
                data = json.load(data_file)
                return data

def json_pprint(json_obj):
        print json.dumps(json_obj,
        sort_keys=False, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))

def flatten_list(mylist):
        result = []
        for item in mylist:
                entry = {}
                entry["name"] = item
                result.append(entry)
        return result

def smart_flatten(myobj):
    if isinstance(myobj, list):
        result_list = flatten_list(myobj);
        return result_list;

    if isinstance(myobj, dict):
        result_list = []
        for key, value in myobj.iteritems():
            r = {}
            r["name"] = key
            r["children"] = smart_flatten(value)

            result_list.append(r)
        return result_list;

if __name__ == "__main__":
        data = load_data("input.json")
        ####data = load_data(sys.stdin)

        mydict = smart_flatten(data)
        json_pprint(mydict)
```

The output is (with a `[]` wrapping the result):

```
[
  {
    "name": "root",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "d3",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Transitions",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "d3.transition"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Selections",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "d3.select"
              },
              {
                "name": "d3.selectAll"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```